# Is it possible to use the NFC ntag413 SUN feature with Web NFC API

Tags: nfc, webnfc

I can't find any infos about the "SUN – Secure Unique NFC Message" fature for the
[Web_NFC_API](https://stackoverflow.com)

Based on [NTAG 413 DNA](https://www.variuscard.com/plastic-cards/smartcard-rfid-nfc-mifare/nfc-ntag-413-dna/?lang=en) The ntag413 sends a unic NDEFMessage. Can I read that with the Web NFC API in any way or can I only read the plain text data on the nfc tag without any protection?

Or is the online validation even made by the phone on scan and it is forwarding only the the raw text when valid?